# What is the maximum number of points in 3-dimensional space such that no four points lie in a common plane?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the maximum number of points in 3-dimensional space such that no four points lie in a common plane?

Can someone explain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You may want to think about the same problem but in 2-dimensional space where no three points lie on a straight line.

Answer (score 4):

This maximum does not exist. You can find infinitely many points in $\mathbb R^3$ such that no $4$ of them lie in a common plane.

Proof by contradiction:
Assume that the maximum exists and is $n\in\mathbb N$. Then there exists a subset $S\subset \mathbb R^3$ consisting of $n$ points such that no $4$ of them lie in a common plane.

Since $n$ was chosen as the maximum, it follows that $\mathbb R^3$ is the union of all planes spanned by three points from $S$. If there was a point that is not contained in that union, we could add it to $S$ which would contradict maximality. But these are only finitely many planes.

So we have that $\mathbb R^3$ is the union of finitely many planes. This is a contradiction, as every plane has lebesgue measure $0$.